# Port 3003 is not working while ports 3000 - 3002 are working fine

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I have several node.js apps on an Ubuntu server working just fine on ports 3000 - 3002. Now I added one more app to port 3003 and it is not working anymore. I switched the apps on port 3002 and 3003 and it's still port 3003 not working, so it's not the app itself causing it.

Also when I do the request from the Ubuntu server itself it is working:

```
$ curl http://<my-domain>:3003/
Hello World!
```

But from outside or from the browser I'm getting a timeout:

```
$ curl http://<my-domain>:3003/
curl: (28) Failed to connect to <my-domain> port 3003 after 21091 ms: Timed out
```

There is nothing in the iptables...

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

... and the UFW is inactive:

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

Here the netstat output:

```
$ netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
[...]
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      28483/node /home/we
tcp6       0      0 :::3001                 :::*                    LISTEN      28489/node /home/we
tcp6       0      0 :::3002                 :::*                    LISTEN      28531/node /home/we
tcp6       0      0 :::3003                 :::*                    LISTEN      28503/node /home/we
[...]
```

What else could it be?

Comment: What do you mean by "from outside"? If it means a different network or the WAN, how is port forwarding done? And was port 3033 added?

Comment: Your comment got me googling again and it turned out that I needed to also add the port in the firewall settings of my server provider.